# Is there any way to write 2d matrix in file without using functions?

Tags: java

I would like to write 10 2d matrix in java (they are sudoku) but i would like to just write them in the file(by hand) without having them in my code in the first place and use them in function to write and read them from file. 
I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using functions"? What format do you want them to be in the file?

Comment: I already know the sudoku boards and I just want to write all the 10 of them in a file and then take them one by one .

Answer (score 1):

You can define the sudoku board as follows

```
    int[][] sudoku = {
        {4, 2, 9,   8, 1, 3,   5, 6, 7},
        {5, 1, 6,   4, 7, 2,   9, 3, 8},
        {7, 8, 3,   6, 5, 9,   2, 4, 1},

        {6, 7, 2,   1, 3, 4,   8, 5, 9},
        {3, 9, 5,   2, 8, 6,   1, 7, 4},
        {8, 4, 1,   7, 9, 5,   6, 2, 3},

        {1, 5, 8,   3, 6, 7,   4, 9, 2},
        {9, 3, 4,   5, 2, 8,   7, 1, 6},
        {2, 6, 7,   9, 4, 1,   3, 8, 5},
    };
```

Comment: In this way I will define my board in the place where I write my code. I want to define an already known sudoku board directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional array and save it to a file using JSON

```
{
  "sudoku": [
    [], [],
    [], [],
    [], [],
    [], [],
    [], [],
    [], [],
    [], []
  ]
}
```

How to create a 2 dimensional array

```java
int[][] twoD_arr = new int[3][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you want:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[][] grid1 = loadGrid(9, 9, "grid_1.txt");
            printGrid(grid1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int[][] loadGrid(int width, int height, String filename) throws IOException {
        int[][] res = new int[width][height];
        int y = 0;
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            int x = 0;
            for (String n : line.split("\\s+"))
                res[y][x++] = Integer.parseInt(n);
            ++y;
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static void printGrid(int[][] grid) {
        for (int[] row : grid) {
            for (int n : row)
                System.out.print(n + "  ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The important bit is in `loadGrid`.  It uses `readAllLines` to get a List of lines from the text file, then within each line split it on the regex `\s+`, which means "any amount of whitespace".  This produces a bunch of individual Strings that you can turn back into numbers.

The input file is just:

```
1  2  3    4  5  6    7  8  9
10 11 12   13 14 15   16 17 18
19 20 21   22 23 24   25 .... etc
```

Beware that this isn't tolerant of mistakes in the source file.  You will need to handle files that have the wrong size, files with non-numeric text in, etc.

Comment: I try to run it but it throws the exception.